# Rails Devise: Don't check password salt when authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, devise, md5

I'm migrating a PHP site over to Rails using Devise as the authentication method. The old site uses md5(salt + password) to authenticate users so I wrote a custom Devise encryptor as such:

```
module Devise
  module Encryptors
    class Md5 < Base
      def self.digest(password, stretches, pepper)
        Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password + 'the_salt_value')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I create a new user on the new site with the password "password", the hashed password matches the user on the old site with the password "password", which is good. However, the values in the password_salt column, whose purpose I'm unclear on, are different and the user on the old site can't login with "password" when I migrate the database over.

What's the best way to deal with this problem? Is there a way to make Devise simply compare the values in the encrypted_password column when authenticating?

Comment: Here's something that does work, but is maybe not the best solution: `def valid_password?(password) { Devise::Encryptors::Md5.digest(password, nil, nil) == self.encrypted_password unless encrypted_password.blank? } (in user.rb)`

Comment: Salt is very important in password encryption. You should take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) . Also, try migrating users from old table to new user(devise) table.